# Why String Array only get to return first element, but not the subsequent element?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line, null, strtok

I am writing this program to convert a string into a string array in C (Using char**). But it seems that the program only get to store the element of the first value, but the rest is just printing (null). May I know what I did wrong here?

Here is a snippet of how I test my code. I am allocating the memory for char**, and passing it to toStrArray functions to store each string in argv[1] to arg_1 (separating by delimeter " ").
Which means everytime the program sees a " ", it marks to stop and store the string into the array element

EXPECTED OUTPUT: This city is beautiful! But  ACTUAL OUTPUT: This (null) (null) (null)

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i; 
    int numWords; /* Pointer size (row) for arg_1 */
    char **arg_1; /* String array for argument 1 */


    if( argc == ARGUMENT_SIZE ) 
    {
        numWords = getNumWords(argv[1]); /* Get the number of words in arg_1 
                                          eg: "This city is beautiful" will return 4 */

        /* Allocation of string array of arg_1 */
        arg_1 = (char**)malloc(numWords * sizeof(char*));

        /* ASSERTION: Iterate through the rows of string array and allocate their memory */
        for( i = 0; i < numWords; i++ )
            *arg_1 = (char*)malloc(STR_LENGTH * sizeof(char));

        arg_1 = toStrArray( argv[1], arg_1, " " ); /* Converts each word in argv[1] to separated string array 
                                                  so that we can find matching with argv[2] and change it */
    
        for( i = 0; i < numWords; i++ )
            printf("%s ", arg_1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So here is my toStrArray

```
char** toStrArray(char str[], char **strArr, char delim[]) 
{
    char *token;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    token = strtok(str, delim);
    /* ASSERTION: Token the string until the end of the string */
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        strArr[i] = token; /* Assigning each word into element array */
        token = strtok(NULL, delim); /* Get the next token (word) */
        i++;
    }
    return strArr;
}
```

getNumWords function:

```
int getNumWords(char str[])
{
    int num_words;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str, " ");
    num_words = 0;

    /* ASSERTION: Iterate until we reach the last token */
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        num_words++;
    }
    return num_words;    
}
```

Comment: Your count of words is one too small, is it not?  The first `strtok()` finds one word, but you set the count to 0, not 1.

Comment: `*arg_1 = (char*)malloc(STR_LENGTH * sizeof(char));` only allocates for the first pointer in `arg_1` (over and over again creating a memory-leark each time you overwrite the prior pointer address). In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` making the inclusion in multiplication superfluous.

Comment: @CalmenChia Each time you call `malloc`, you are assigning it to `*arg1` which overwrites the previous memory allocated to it. This creates a memory leak, since the previous memory was never freed. This is also not what you want. You want to assign each newly allocated memory to the next location within the string array, `arg1`. Hence, you should increment that pointer when assigning newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `strtok` twice on the same character array in memory. The input

```
char str = {'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'c', 'i', 't', 'y', ' ', 'i', 's',
            ' ', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'u', 't', 'i', 'f', 'u', 'l', '!',  0};
```

will become

```
char str = {'T', 'h', 'i', 's',   0, 'c', 'i', 't', 'y',   0, 'i', 's',
              0, 'b', 'e', 'a', 'u', 't', 'i', 'f', 'u', 'l', '!',  0};
```

after executing

```c
char* ret1 = strtok(str,  " "); // Sets the null byte after 'This'
char* ret2 = strtok(NULL, " "); // Sets the null byte after 'city'
char* ret3 = strtok(NULL, " "); // Sets the null byte after 'is'
char* ret4 = strtok(NULL, " "); // Doesn't modify str
```

Note that each whitespace character is replaced with a terminating null byte. Doing so will cut the input string into multiple substrings:

```
printf("%s\n", ret1); // Outputs 'This'
printf("%s\n", ret2); // Outputs 'city'
printf("%s\n", ret3); // Outputs 'is'
printf("%s\n", ret4); // Outputs 'beautiful!'
```

If you call `toStrArray`, this has already happened and a call to `strtok` with `argv[1]` returns NULL because the substring 'This' doesn't contain a separator.

Therefore I would suggest counting the number of separators with `strchr` instead: It return a pointer to the first appearance of a character. From there, the search continues until no more whitespaces can be found, i.e. NULL is returned.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "This city is beautiful!";

    int count = 0;
    for(char* tmp = str; tmp; count++) {
        while (tmp[1] == ' ')     // Ignore preceding and multiple whitespaces
            tmp++;
        tmp = strchr(tmp+1, ' '); // Find next whitespace
    }

    printf("Number of words: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Beware multiple spaces in the string (`This  city  is  beautiful`).  You might do better using interleaved `strcspn()` and `strspn()` calls — `strcspn()` to find the tokens, and `strspn()` to find sequences of blanks.  Remember, `strtok()` skips multiple occurrences of the separator characters.

Comment: the second for loop condition "tmp;" in for(char* tmp = str; tmp; count++).  
Is it equivalent to tmp != NULL?

Comment: @CalmenChia Yes, it is: since there is no boolean data type in C, any non-zero expression is interpreted as true. So `tmp` is a shorthand for `tmp != NULL`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your comment. I've added some code to intercept preceding and multiple whitespaces. Trailing ones are not taken into account, but I want to keep it simple.